# How do the various means of finding unanswered questions differ?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

There are various ways to find unanswered questions on a site, but all those ways come to totally different results and I'd like to understand why this is. Note that I am very well aware that under some circumstances SE defines "unanswered" as having no upvoted or accepted answers. I'm not here to discusss this notion and its advantages. In this question I am concentrating solely on questions **with no (undeleted) answer at all**. Also forgive me if this is actually a duplicate, but I'd like to reach a somewhat exhaustive conclusion on the matter here.

So let's take a look at how we can find questions with no answer and let's take this site here (including the *different* numbers at the time of asking):

1. ['Questions' section, 'unanswered' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered): **8,074**.
2. ['Unanswered' section, 'newest' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest): **7,868**.
3. ['Unanswered' section, 'no answers' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers): **7,823**.
4. [searching for `is:question answers:0 closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano): **7,832**.
5. [searching for `is:question answers:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0): **15,238**.

I know that some of those things ought to be different, e.g. 2 has more than 3 because it includes 0-score unaccepted answers, and 5 has more than 4 because it includes closed ones. However, I included those queries here to maybe see some correlation to other queries, but there is none. For example why is 1 different from all of 2, 3 and 4? What are the additional conditions those different queries operate under?

And last but not least, **what is the best and most reliable solution to find each and every non-closed undeleted question that doesn't have any undeleted answers**, disregarding any question votes or whatever?

Comment: Your #4 is the answer to the question in the last paragraph. Two remarks: you may want to add `locked:0` because you can't answer locked non-closed questions (luckily there are few of those). The parameter `is:question` is unnecessary when your query includes `answers:0`; the latter already implies you are searching for questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. ['Questions' section, 'unanswered' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered): **8,074**.

This is the section for questions that have **no answers with score > 0**. So  some of the questions *do* have answers, but they have a score of 0 or less. Also, it excludes closed questions.

2. ['Unanswered' section, 'newest' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest): **7,868**.

This tab have the same content as the above one **but excludes questions with score <0**. Therefore the number of questions in this tab is smaller than the number of question of the above tab.

3. ['Unanswered' section, 'no answers' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers): **7,823**.

This tab has questions with **no answers at all** (question score is, again, > -1). The number of questions it this tab shows is therefore smaller.

4. [searching for `is:question answers:0 closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano): **7,832**.

Works almost in the same way as above, but also includes questions with score < 0. **This is the best way to find you are looking for and the most accurate.**

5. [searching for `is:question answers:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0): **15,238**.

Questions with no answers, but, unlike all the previous variants, includes closed questions.